# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: Once I got Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

I just upgraded to Xcode 8 and now my app does not work. It shows these error messages.

```
 ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/Connor/Desktop/Print start/Print'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-Fstart/StarPrinting'
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Connor/Desktop/Print start/Print start/libStarPrinting.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Users/Connor/Desktop/Print start/Print start/libStarPrinting.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Connor/Desktop/Print start/Print start/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore.tbd, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/Connor/Desktop/Print start/Print start/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore.tbd (3 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Connor/Desktop/Print start/Print start/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics.tbd, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/Connor/Desktop/Print start/Print start/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics.tbd (3 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/Connor/Desktop/Print start/Print start/UIKit.framework/UIKit.tbd, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/Connor/Desktop/Print start/Print start/UIKit.framework/UIKit.tbd (3 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIAlertView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIResponder", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_AppDelegate in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_ViewController in ViewController.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_UIResponder", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_AppDelegate in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_UIViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ViewController in ViewController.o
  "_UIApplicationMain", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have been looking into this for a while and have not found a solution that worked for me. I hope this helps any one else who might have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by deleting some of the Frameworks search paths and it ran perfectly. I am still not sure how this was effected by just updating to Xcode 8.

Comment: What do you mean by  'deleting some of the Frameworks search paths' can you please elaborate